# How to get the correct acces token for Firebase Dynamic Link Analytics Rest API (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, rest, firebase-analytics, firebase-admin, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a problem with my access_token which I get with the serveracceskey. Here is my code in NodeJS:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var request = require("request");
const serviceAccount = require('./serverAccountKey.json');
const credential =  admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount);

  credential.getAccessToken().then((accessTokenInfo) => {
  const accessToken = accessTokenInfo.access_token;
  const expirationTime = accessTokenInfo.expires_in;
  console.log("accessToken " + accessToken );
  console.log("expirationTime " +expirationTime);

    var s = "Bearer " + accessToken;
    request({
    headers:{
        'Authorization': s
    },
    uri:"https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/SHORTLINK/linkStats?durationDays=7",
    method: "GET",

    }, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

and the result is like below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? I test the link in Postman too. Something is wrong, I read all the firebase Rest API Doc.

Comment: this is critical bug, firebase team should fix this. Firebase dynamic link is useless if we cannot doing the analytic. What is the difference with usual shortener url?

Answer (score 1):

Admin SDK creates tokens with a specific set of scopes: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/auth/credential.ts#L272

Clearly, Dynamic Links API requires additional OAuth2 scopes in the token. You're better off using some OAuth2 library for this use case. If you were using Java or Python, Google Cloud provides libraries that handles this for you.

Comment: thanks for your response. As you mentioned for the access_token need the scopes and I put one of them but I still get the same error. I read this documentation a lot.(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics). I need to know  which scope is the perfect for give the analytics response.

Comment: We opened internal issue to improve samples code/documentation.

Comment: I know but I can't find a component for this issue,  I can't create the issue and for the Firebase Component, I don't have the permission for creating an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with a helpful GitHub user. If anyone get the same problem,press this link it will be helped. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/111