# Firebase Dynamic Links - how to send additional data inside the link?

Tags: firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'd like to create a deep link using Firebase Dynamic Links.

I have read the documentation and in order to create the deep link using REST API, 
one need to create HTTP POST request with a JSON object as the following:

```
{"dynamicLinkInfo": 
{
"dynamicLinkDomain": "abc123.app.goo.gl",
"link": "https://example.com/",
"androidInfo": {
  "androidPackageName": "com.example.android"
},
"iosInfo": {
  "iosBundleId": "com.example.ios"
}
}
```

My question is - I'd like to send additional data to the application, inside the link. How can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To add more data to the deep link, append the data as query parameters. In your example the deep link is `https://example.com`. Modify this to `https://example.com/inviteWithPromo?promotionID=123&payload=abcdef&inviterID=3435`.

Also check out this related answer [How to generate a dynamic link for a specific post in android firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703215/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-link-for-a-specific-post-in-android-firebase/45704583#45704583)

Comment: How about replace "https://example.com/" in your JSON with "https://example.com/inviteWithPromo?promotionID=123&payload=abcdef&inviterID=3435" . Or I am missing something?